# How to create pagination to display array using "for" loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, show

```
for($i=0;  $i<sizeof($allTags);  $i++) {
            if($allTags[$i]!='') {
        $qa_content['custom'.++$c] = '<article>// <div class="custom.."
                <header><a href="tag/'.urlencode($allTags[$i]).'"><h2>'.$allTags[$i].'</h2></a></header>
                <div>'.$SameTagsCount[$allTags[$i]].'</div>
                </article>';
            }
```

`$allTags` is an array with more than 1k inside it. How to display it in several pages so that each page contains N divs?

Comment: And what you have tried?

Comment: I have no idea. The page is loading for a quite long time. I'm looking for solution

Comment: @Sardor what is size of `$allTags` array?

Comment: I looked through page pagination questions, seems it's above me knowledge

Comment: Is it possible for example. user opens page and it shows 10 html blocks, then if he clicks to "more" page will reload or without it shows 10 more html  and so on...

Comment: `seems it's above me knowledge` - then learn. Start with a basic pagination tutorial.

Comment: @OfirBaruch thanks for your advice. If you have mentioned I'm trying to do "learn". Could you help me to implement pagination for the loop above...

Answer (score 0):

What you talking about is nothing but pagination. There are many ready made plugins available to use or you can code one.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Could you give some links for those which can be used with this loop

Comment: For using any plugin you cannot directly use your code in that plugin you will need to according to the document of that plugin.